# delete row with value excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a code that looks for a file extension then deletes that row.This is what I have so far

```
With Worksheets("ImportSheet")
For lRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "*xlsx" Then
        Rows(lRow).Delete
    End If
Next
End With
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Help greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Worksheets("ImportSheet")
For lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(lRow, 1).Value Like "*xlsx" Then
        Rows(lRow).Delete
    End If
Next
End With
```